# Parsing XML through XSLT Transforms

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

I have some XML in this format

```
<items>
    <item>
    <float>0.75</float>
    <string>NAME</string>
    <string>Bob</string>
    <string>CREATION_TIME</string>
    <timestamp>2012-11-01 00:03:08</timestamp>
    <string>OCCUPATION</string>
    <null />
    </item>
</items>
```

I'd like to transform it to a format like this

```
<item>
    <NAME>Bob</NAME>
    <CREATION_TIME>2012-11-01 00:03:08</CREATION_TIME>
    <OCCUPATION></OCCUPATION>
</item>
```

Is it possible to do it through plain XSLT transforms or would I have to write my own parser?

Comment: Can you explain which child elements of `item` elements you want to process and which ones you want to relate? Why is the `float` ignored, which elements should be paired to create a `<some-name>some value</some-name>` result element?

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="string[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
  <xsl:element name="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 - one quick item: your solution completely removes the `<OCCUPATION>` element, whereas the OP's expected solution retains it.

Comment: @ABach, you are right, I am currently not sure what determines which elements to process and relate. I will ask the poster.

Comment: @MartinHonnen If you number all the strings, the odd ones are the keys and the even ones are the values.

Comment: @Narabhut, the `<xsl:apply-templates select="string[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>` takes the odd `string` elements but that way the `<string>OCCUPATION</string>` is not treated as a key (as it is the 4th `string`). Is that what you want?